# MUI Menu positioning based on available space

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to position the menu popup when the select field is clicked on.

As per default the menu obscures the select dropdown field if there not enough space below the field.

I want the menu to display aligned with the select field, below the field with some spacing and alighed with the select field on the left side.
Incase there is not enough space below in the page, the menu should display above the select field.

I'm pretty much new to ui development.

Any help is appreciated...

```js
<Select
  fullWidth
  select
  sx={{
    height: 35,
    color: "black",
    ".MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      borderColor:
        selectRecordColorChange && selectRecordColorChange(row.columnHeader)
          ? "red"
          : null,
    },
  }}
  MenuProps={{
    PaperProps: { sx: { maxHeight: "450px" } },
  }}
  defaultValue={
    selectRecordChange(row.mappedHeader).length !== 0
      ? selectRecordChange(row.mappedHeader)[0]
      : valueSelect
  }
  onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, row.columnHeader)}
>
                   
  {mapperDropdown
    .map((val) => {
      return val.includes("*") ? val.split("*").join("") : val;
    })
    .map((option) => (
      <MenuItem key={option} value={option}>
        {option}                     
      </MenuItem>
    ))}
  <MenuItem key={"No Mapping"} value={"No Mapping"}>
    No Mapping                  
  </MenuItem>               
</Select>
```

I have tried `MenuProps`. But not getting the result I want. Still obscuring the select field.

```js
MenuProps={{
  anchorOrigin: {
    vertical: "bottom",
    horizontal: "left",
  },
  transformOrigin: {
    vertical: "top",
    horizontal: "left",
  },
  getContentAnchorEl: null,
  MenuListProps: {
    style: {
      marginTop: (theme) => theme.spacing(1),
    },
    autoFocus: false,
    variant: "menu",
  },
  PaperProps: {
    sx: { maxHeight: "450px" },
  },
}}
```

Comment: could you post a runnable example ?